# What is the fastest way generating an iterator with all permutations with 25 length of only 3 repetitive elements in Python?

Tags: python, permutation

What I have tried is defining a list with enough repetitive elements in it, then put it in itertools.permutation following a set definition to eliminate repetitions. Codes are shown below:

```
basic = [0]*25 + [1]*25 +[2]*25
completed_set = set(itertools.permutations(basic))
```

It seems like it takes a lot of time to complete its computation. So I have searched for another method using itertools.product, which is way more faster but costing most of my computer's memory:

```
completed_set = [p for p in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=25)]
```

Is there any other way which would be either faster and less RAM-occupying than the aboves to complete this task?

Comment: `product(range(3), repeat=25)` is an iterator. `[p for p in product(range(3), repeat=25)]` is a list. Do you actually need a list?

Comment: Do you really want `product(range(3), repeat=25)`?  That gives you tuples of length  25, not tuples of length 75 (which is what your earlier `permutation` yields).

Comment: Generating permutations time complexity grows at factorial rate.  So no matter what you do it is always going to take a long time.  factorial of 25 is `15511210043330985984000000`  so you can see why it would take a long time

Comment: `itertools.permutations(basic)` would yield ~ 2×10^109 items, while the `set()` would contain 7×10^33 items. This set would not fit into memory (to put it mildly), and there is not enough time before the heat death of the universe to calculate all of them.